# Http request in Cordova not work on android platform

Tags: angular, cordova, cordova-plugins

i have create a cordova project use android platform, but my http request to end point never got response. i always get response status 0. that mean not connect to network. I already install the cordova whitelist plugin. This my project  https://github.com/localhouse/cordova-android-http-request.  
Cordova "www" folder source,  i create using Angular 8

Comment: any mean you can paste the code snippet? the repo has build files, cant be of much help with them.

Comment: how do you genarate project

Comment: im using cordova cli

Comment: Thanks guys for response mu question. I found the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo   .maybe because im using the httpendpoint with IP Address

Comment: Check this once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56178450/ajax-calls-dont-work-on-phonegap-apk-build/56238987#56238987

Comment: @RamprasathSelvam already try that method, but not work. my issue solved by using this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752716/why-am-i-seeing-neterr-cleartext-not-permitted-errors-after-upgrading-to-cordo is to allow clear text communication